# how to compare /insert dates from two different columns

Tags: vba, excel, date, comparison

Hi， I am new to vba and I am stuck in a project when I need to compare the price on certain security from two different pricing source.

In the excel Col A - E belongs to the first source, and F-I belongs to the second source, where A and F contains the date, and B/G C/H D/I each contains bid, ask, close price respectively of the date on A/F respectively...

What I want to compare is if all the date on A and F are matched or if there are any missing dates.

If there are any missing date on any source I want to insert the missing date and highlight the missing date with color, and leave the cells in B-E/ G-I blank on the missing date.

Following is my code:

```
 Dim lastRow As Long
    lastRow = wks.Range("A3").End(xlDown).Row


    For i = 4 To lastRow Step 1
       acell = wks.Cells(i, 1).Value
       fcell = wks.Cells(i, 6).Value

        If acell <> fcell Then
           If acell > fcell Then
           wks.Range("A3:A90", "C3:C90").Rows(i).Insert xlShiftDown
           wks.Cells(i, 1) = fcell
           wks.Cells(i, 1).Interior.Color = vbRed
           End If

           If fcell > acell Then
           wks.Range("F3:F90", "I3:I90").Rows(i).Insert xlShiftDown
           wks.Cells(i, 6) = acell
           wks.Cells(i, 6).Interior.Color = vbRed
           End If
        End If
    Next i
```

When I ran this macro the result is not what i have imagined..There are a lot of blank rows in between in random colors..

I am completely new to coding so I might not have chosen the best structure for the problem. Any idea how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In excel, I'm not recommend insert or delete rows in source worksheet. Better copy each value on new sheet.

IMHO a good way is iterate through list of all dates and find certain date in source worksheet. It is the less complicated algorithm:

Some simple code:

```
Dim Filled As Boolean

Set ListWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set SrcWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)
Set DestWks = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(3)

DestWks.UsedRange.EntireRow.Clear

For i = 1 To ListWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Filled = False
    For k = 2 To SrcWks.UsedRange.Rows.Count ' k = 1 - header
        If ListWks.Cells(i, "A").Value = SrcWks.Cells(k, "A").Value Or _
        ListWks.Cells(i, "A").Value = SrcWks.Cells(k, "F").Value Then
            DestWks.Range("A" & i & ":i" & i).Value = SrcWks.Range("A" & k & ":i" & k).Value
            Filled = True
            GoTo break_k_loop
        End If
    Next k
break_k_loop:
    If Not Filled Then DestWks.Cells(i, "A").EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbRed
Next i
```

**PS1** A good idea is work with first source ("A:E") and second ("F:I") independent. For good view you may write "status" each date on `ListWks`.
Ranges must be continuous and don't forget sort them by dates.

```
If SrcWks.Range("a1") <> "" Then
    With SrcWks
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("a1:e1").AutoFilter
    End With
    With SrcWks.AutoFilter.Sort
        .SortFields.Clear
        .SortFields.Add Key:=Range("a1"), SortOn:=xlsortonvalue, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End If
```

So, full pseudocode:

```
clear_destination_wks

apply_filter_on_first_source
loop_through_datelist_with_first_source
    if date_present then 
        copy_range_to_DestWks       
        write_status_on_listWks_for_example_2
    else
        write_status_on_listWks_for_example_1
    end if

apply_filter_on_second_source
loop_through_datelist_with_first_source
    if date_present then
        copy_range_to_DestWks
        write_status_on_listWks_for_example_PRESENT
    elseif status_on_listWks = 1
        write_status_on_listWks_for_example_NOT_PRESENT
        DestWks.interior.color = vbRed
    end if

clear_all_filters
```

**PS2:** If for some reason you need use the way you described you shouldn't forget increase counter and loop bound while you insert rows.

```
For i = 4 To lastRow
    If reason = True Then
        wks.Rows(i).Insert xlShiftDown ' instead Range("A3:A90", "C3:C90")
        i = i + 1
        lastRow = lastRow + 1
    End If
next i
```